# Override parent class init value when using unittest mock

Tags: subclass, python-unittest

I have a class that is initialized like so:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.network = id
        self.requester = CompanyRequest()
```

To run tests for this class, I am mocking `CompanyRequest` so that I can define its return values. Since `Parent` only takes in `id` as a parameter I define a subclass:

```
class MockParent(Parent):
    @patch("CompanyRequest")
    def __init__(self, id, mock_request):
        self.network = id
        self.requester = mock_request
```

This works fine when testing and gives me the expected behavior. My issue is that for code review I get an error saying `__init__ method from base class 'Parent' is not called`. However if I call `super().__init__(id)` then it will try to call the real `CompanyRequest` instead of the `mock_request`, which causes all sorts of problems since the whole point of this is to test the `Parent` class methods on known return values.

Is there a way to override the parent `__init__` function in a subclass? Or possibly a way to mock/bypass it?

Comment: You just have to mock `ComapnyRequest` in your test instead of writing your own derived mock, e.g. something like `@patch("module_path.parent_module.CompanyRequest", mock_request)`.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, in `MockParent` I set `self.requester = mock_request`. The `Parent` class only takes in `id` as a parameter so in order to use `mock_request` instead of `CompanyRequest` I define my own init.

Comment: I may have not been clear - what I mean is, you don't need to overwrite `__init__`, you just need to mock `CompanyRequest` (the one that is called in the production code, make sure to use the correct path), and you have to use `patch` on the _test_, not on a derived class. You wil find tons of examples here and in the documentation.

Comment: Ah, got it. This is my first time really messing around with `patch` so I wasn't familiar with some stuff. I was mocking `modules.company.request.CompanyRequest` when I should have been mocking `modules.parent.CompanyRequest`. Thanks!